# Acceder a una clase Java interna

Tags: java

¿Por qué no es un problema acceder en dos tiempos a una clase java interna:

```
Clause.Litteral l = (Clause.Litteral)copieResolvante.listeLitteraux.get(0);

if(l.predicat.equals("write")){
                    Clause.Litteral.Symbole s = (Clause.Litteral.Symbole)l.get(0);
                    System.out.println("VOILA CE QU'IL Y AVAIT AU CHALET: " + s + "\n\n\n");
```

...y sí es un problema cuando tratamos de hacerlo en un solo tiempo?

```
while((Clause.Litteral)copieResolvante.listeLitteraux.get(cptrLit).predicat.equals("write")){
```

Ésta es la arquitectura de nuestro programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al parecer el problema está aquí:

```
(Clause.Litteral)copieResolvante.listeLitteraux.get(cptrLit).predicat
//..........................................................| no se sabe que predicat es parte de lo retornado por listeLitteraux.get(cptrLit)
```

Debes utilizar paréntesis para agrupar la variable o el valor sobre el que necesitas hacer el casteo, y luego llamar al atributo o método correspondiente, de esta manera:

```
((Clause.Litteral)copieResolvante.listeLitteraux.get(cptrLit)).predicat
```

Así, tu código luciría (puesto en múltiples líneas para entender su significado):

```
while(
    (
        //castear a Clause.Litteral el resultado de
        //copieResolvante.listeLitteraux.get(cptrLit)
        (Clause.Litteral)copieResolvante.listeLitteraux.get(cptrLit)
    ).predicat //sobre ese resultado, acceder al atributo predicat
    .equals("write")) { //sobre el atributo predicat. acceder al método equals
}
```

Sin embargo, como buena práctica para legibilidad de código, puesto que según el código que muestras vas a utilizar luego otros atributos/métodos del resultado de `(Clause.Litteral)copieResolvante.listeLitteraux.get(cptrLit)`, lo mejor sería almacenar este resultado en una variable.